# Using OracleDB OS.Environment Password

Tags: python, oracle

I am trying to connect to an oracle database with Python code. I am using the OracleDB package but want it so that the user is able to connect to the DB with their own password machine and password rather than coding it into the code itself.

So far I have this,

```
import oracledb
import os

username=os.environ.get("Username")
pw=os.environ.get("pasword")
conn =  oracledb.connect(user=username, password=pw, host="url", port=0000, service_name="service"
```

Comment: What issue are you having with your code - do you get an error? (You've spelled `"pasword"` with one 's' instead of two; maybe that's your issue?)

Comment: sorry, that is a typo. It should be just "Password" The issue really is just how to set it up so that it takes the environment password that they have set so that they can connect to the oracle database

Comment: Setting user credentials in environment variables is a *bad* idea, as these variables are often visible to other users of the same system, or to administrators, and can be captured in audit data. Likewise, OS authentication is often a bad idea too: Oracle doesn't match the client and username: if a hacker creates a valid username on another machine, Oracle will accept that login too. Your code either needs to prompt the user to enter credentials, or use something like Windows AD authentication or some other supported network credential for single-sign-on capability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source the environment variables (Make them available to the python process)

```
$cat env.sh
export USERNAME=app_schema
export PASSWORD=secret

$cat connect.py
import oracledb
import os

username=os.environ.get("USERNAME")
pw=os.environ.get("PASSWORD")
conn = oracledb.connect(user=username, password=pw, host="localhost", port=1521, service_name="XEPDB1")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('select dummy from dual')
for row in c:
    print (row[0])
conn.close()

$ # source the variables (note the dot)
$. env.sh
$python connect.py
X
```

Best of luck!